# GitLab CI - Move pipeline logic from a project repo to centralized "devops-repo"

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a great experience of pipeline creating automation (in case of huge amount of repos).
For example, a project has 20 similar repos with Java app (like a microservice) and a pipeline for each of them is differing only by repo url (and a few more minor attributes). The CI/CD process for each of them is the same.

So, we can create a separated devops-repo with declaration configuration for our services. Also we can create a single pipeline which will pull the devops repo and create all needed pipelines for each repo in the configuration (this operation is going to be executed only once in the beginning and in case if we want to change the devops-configuration)

I have implemented that using Jenkins. Now, I am going to do so using GitLab CI. But I can't get how is it possible.

Is it possible to create a pipeline from another one (dynamically)?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) and put the generic pipeline in your devops repo.
In your java repos you can include the devops pipeline and set the variables which are specific for the respective java repo.

So the pipeline for your java repos can be as short as this:

```
include:
  - project: 'your-group/devops-repository'
    file: '.generic-ci.yml'

variables:
  FOO: bar
```

Comment: as an option, yes. but I have to put this config in each repo. In case of Jenkins there is a "jenkinsfile" but it is better (imho) to avoid this.